# ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail is not work in samsung tablet 10.1

Tags: android, video, thumbnails

I try to create a thumbnail of android SD card video. This are the function i use to create video thumbnail

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("sdCard_Video_Path",MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

But I get video thumbnail in all phone without samsung tablet  10.1. In  `samsung tablet  10.1` it show black thumbnail.

Why this function is not work in `samsung tablet  10.1`

I am also check that the bitmap is null or not

```
if (thumb != null) {
imageView.setImageBitmap(thumb);
```

But the `samsung tablet  10.1` do not give any null bitmap but it show black in thumbnail

```
help via comment or link.
```

Comment: Hi @Md Abdul Gafur, did you find any solution ? Am also facing same issue in Samsung M30s device.

Comment: Make sure your file extension is .mp4. Am also faced same issue in Samsung devices after updating the file extension its working fine for all devices.

Answer (score 1):

You should copy Android source code (`ThumbnailUtils.java`) to your code
and replace `createVideoThumbnail` function, change `setDataSource(link)` to `setDataSource(link, new HashMap());`

Reference: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35794

Comment: Did you actually do this and get it to work? If so can you give some detail how you went about it - ThumbnailUtils.java uses some hidden API's and won't obviously compile, in Eclipse anyway, from what I could see.